# Findbugs NP_ARGUMENT_MIGHT_BE_NULL not being triggered as expected

Tags: java, findbugs

I am using Findbugs together with the annotation javax.annotation.Nonnull. In following method

```
@Nonnull
public String methodA(@Nonnull String foo, @Nonnull Integer bar) {
    // missing checkNotNull(foo)
    // missing checkNotNull(bar)
    
    int fooLen = foo.length();    // did not check that foo is non-null
    
    return (bar < fooLen)? foo : null; // did not check that bar is non-null
}
```

the params foo and bar are declared to be non-null, and they are subsequently dereferenced without first being checked if they are null.
When I run Findbugs against the code (using the Gradle Findbugs plugin), the Findbugs report does not include the expected warning NP_ARGUMENT_MIGHT_BE_NULL. From the Findbugs website, the description of NP_ARGUMENT_MIGHT_BE_NULL:

> NP: Method does not check for null argument (NP_ARGUMENT_MIGHT_BE_NULL)
>
> A parameter to this method has been identified as a value that should always be checked to see whether or not it is null, but it is being dereferenced without a preceding null check.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've told findbugs that `foo` and `bar` are `@Nonnull`. This tells findbugs to look at invocations of `methodA` for the possibility of arguments being `null` and reject these if it finds them.

Within the method, **precisely because** they are annotated with `@Nonnull`, findbugs assumes they can't be `null` and therefore allows you to use them directly.

You might want to annotate the parameters with `@CheckForNull` for the behavior you expect.

Comment: No, I think there is some configuration missing. In the past, using Findbugs within Eclipse or as a Maven plugin, it would give the NP_ARGUMENT_MIGHT_BE_NULL warning. Also, changing '@'Nonnull to '@"CheckForNull did not generate the warning.

Comment: @user664894 If you really think so, feel free to update your question with your Findbugs configuration. All I can say is that it works for me. `@CheckForNull` warns correctly.